# Converting webpage to pdf including google map but map not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf-generation

I have a  element which contains some content with google map in it.
While trying to convert the div element to pdf everything is fine except google map is not showing.

my js code is

```
function saveAspdf() {
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('content'),{
function() {
pdf.save('web.pdf');
} });
}
```

Comment: the reason because map is in iframe and  jsPDF wont be able to read context from it and also not be able to read cross origin data

Comment: so it does not have any solution? i am using static map, in <img> tag     <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284
&key=AIzaSyAG6wX7egxtDlth16c9GexGYwgqBxKcAxs"/>

Comment: try to save that image in your local and then try m sure you'll get the output

Comment: can you tell me how to use useCORS:true in it

Comment: actually, I got the solution, the solution was to add useCORS: true, and it did the job